# How to keep showing the last video frame

Tags: mediaelement.js

How to keep showing the last video frame when video is finished?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your options

```
autoRewind: false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var videoPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer('#homepage-player', {
    loop: false,
    features:[],
    enablePluginDebug: false,
    plugins: ['flash','silverlight'],
    pluginPath: '/js/mediaelement/',
    flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
    silverlightName: 'silverlightmediaelement.xap',

    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
        // add event listener
        mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
            mediaElement.pause();
            mediaElement.setCurrentTime(mediaElement.duration);
        }, false);
    },
    error: function () { 
    }

});

videoPlayer.play();
```

Does this help ?

Update#1:

```
var player = $('#myvideo').mediaelementplayer();

player.media.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    player.media.setCurrentTime(player.media.duration);
}, false);
```

Comment: No, the behaviour stays unchanged :(

Comment: Also instead on the media.duration add the last second on the movie

Comment: Still no joy. The "ended" event is fired properly in both solutions. Just after the end the video disappears, player positions at the beginning and the circled play sign appears on top of video. I'm using it with IE9 but behaviour appears to be same on other browsers too.

Comment: I'm not an expert,sorry.Let's hope someone else will answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to edit 'mediaelement-and-player.min.js' (if you are using that)... do a text search for c.media.setCurrentTime(0) and comment it out or delete it.